# Parameter with odbc error

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, odbc

i have a problem with supply parameter to store procedure with `odbc`, this is my procedure in `module form Public cmd As OdbcCommand`

```
Private Sub cmdapprove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdapprove.Click
    cmd = New OdbcCommand("select * from mk_cuti where mk_nik='" & txtnik.Text & "'", conn)
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
    rd.Read()
    rd.Close()
    Call opendb()
    If txtstatus.Text = 1 Then
        Using (conn)
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_update_data_trans_cuti_terbawa"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mk_nik", Me.txtnik.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        Dim updatestatus_hrd As String = "Update input_cuti set status_hrd=1 " & _
        "where no_input='" & txtnoinput.Text & "'"
        cmd = New OdbcCommand(updatestatus_hrd, conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Call datacutikaryawan()
    Else
        Dim updatestatus_hrd As String = "Update input_cuti set status_hrd=1 " & _
        "where no_input='" & txtnoinput.Text & "'"
        cmd = New OdbcCommand(updatestatus_hrd, conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Call datacutikaryawan()
    End If

End Sub
```

when i run this procedure, i got massage this

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Procedure
>   or function 'sp_update_data_trans_cuti_terbawa' expects parameter
>   '@mk_nik', which was not supplied.

I think anyone can help me? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one with your class:

```
Dim conn As New OdbcConnection(sConnString)
conn.Open()
Dim sqlCommand As String = "sp_update_data_trans_cuti_terbawa @mk_nik='" & Me.txtnik.Text & "'"

Dim command As New OdbcCommand(sqlCommand)
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
command.Connection = conn
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Aight, I'm off to the nearest pub.

Answer (score 0):

```
conn.execute("sp_update_data_trans_cuti_terbawa @mk_nik='" & Me.txtnik.Text & "'")
```

Comment: After "If txtstatus.Text = 1 Then" replacing the whole "Using" clause

Comment: show 'execute' is not a member of 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection'.

Comment: Member of the ADODB.Connection, since I had no way to guess what class you were using for the conn.

Comment: the connection up there, whats wrong with the class?

Comment: there was no definition of the conn object, so I used the simplest one - adodb.conn

Answer (score 0):

I have module with this

Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Data
Module koneksi
    Public conn As OdbcConnection
    Public str As String
    Public da As OdbcDataAdapter
    Public ds As DataSet
    Public cmd As OdbcCommand
    Public rd As OdbcDataReader

```
Sub opendb()
    str = "Dsn=pmscuti;database=att2000;server=pams-01;uid=sa;pwd=pams123"
    conn = New OdbcConnection(str)
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        Try
            conn.Open()
            'MsgBox("Connection Successfully")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Application.Exit()

        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

End Module

can i know where the problem?